# How to run CLI on docker desktop on windows11

Tags: docker, docker-cli

I am new to docker world. I have installed docker desktop for windows on my win11 machine.
When I run docker version. I get this below information.

Can someone please guide me on how I can get docker CLI working so that I can get an interactive window of the run-time containers.

Comment: In your question there are no information about the error/warning/anomaly you are receiving. Please, revise it.

Comment: I don't know how I can get CLI after downloading and installing docker desktop on windows. I did not try anything yet as I don't know the process.

Comment: The CLI should be installed along with Docker desktop. If that is not working, then it might have something wrong with the service or the installation. Have you confirmed the service is running? Can you open the Docker Desktop UI?

Comment: I can open using this command - docker exec -it <containername> /bin/bash
thanks for your response